# Limit of exponential

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Can anyone help me to prove this:

> For $k\in \mathbb{R}^+$ show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} k^{2n}/n! =0$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k^2)^n}{n!}.$$ Does this series look familiar?  Does it converge? If it does, what can we conclude about the limit of the sequence?

Comment: This looks a little bit like a congruence monoid.

Comment: @Vadim hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\dfrac{k^{2n}}{n!}$. Calculate $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. After a little simplification we get $\dfrac{k^2}{n+1}$.

Let $N$ be the smallest integer greater than $2k^2$, and let $B=a_N$. Note that if $n\ge N$, then $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Thus $a_{N+m}\lt \dfrac{B}{2^m}$. This approaches $0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{k^{2n}}{n!}$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{k^2}{n+1}\rightarrow 0$, thus $a_n\rightarrow 0$.